# trouble getting php checkbox values to show up in resulting email

Tags: php, email, checkbox, foreach

I've been looking for an answer for hours, and have tried multiple solutions from these boards and others, and I still can't find the answer.

I'm really only looking to receive the checkbox data from the form, by email.

Here's the relevant code from dibs.php:

---

```
<form action="mailer.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('from','','RisEmail','subject','','R','verif_box','','R','message','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">


a004 <input type="checkbox" name="dibs[]" value="a004"><br />

z004 <input type="checkbox" name="dibs[]" value="z004"><br />

m003 <input type="checkbox" name="dibs[]" value="m003"><br />


<p>your e-mail address:</p>

<input name="from" type="text" id="from" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #666666; width:180px; height:12px;" value="<?php echo $_GET['from'];?>">

<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="shoe dibs">

<p>please retype the image below into the box:</p>

<input name="verif_box" type="text" id="verif_box" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #666666; width:180px; height:12px;">

<img src="verificationimage.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>" alt="verification image, type it in the box" width="50" height="24" align="absbottom" >


<!-- if the variable "wrong_code" is sent from previous page then display the error field -->

<?php if(isset($_GET['wrong_code'])){?>

<div style="border:1px solid #666666; background-color:#990000; color:#FFFFFF; padding:2px; width:280px;"><b>WRONG VERIFICATION CODE</b></div><br> 

<?php ;}?>

<input name="submit" type="submit" style="margin-top:10px; display:block; border:1px solid #666666; width:100px; height:20px; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:2px; color="#666666;" value="send your dibs">

</form>
```

---

And the code from mailer.php:

---

```
<?php

// load the variables form address bar
$subject = $_REQUEST["subject"];
$message = $_REQUEST["message"];
$from = $_REQUEST["from"];
$verif_box = $_REQUEST["verif_box"];

foreach($_POST["dibs"]  as  $value)  {
$dibs .= "$value\n";
}


// remove the backslashes that normally appears when entering " or '
$message = stripslashes($message); 
$subject = stripslashes($subject); 
$from = stripslashes($from); 

// check to see if verificaton code was correct
if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
// if verification code was correct send the message and show this page
mail("email@mydomain.com", 'Online Form: '.$subject, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\n".$message, "From: $from");
// delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
setcookie('tntcon','');
} else {
// if verification code was incorrect then return to contact page and show error
header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?subject=$subject&from=$from&message=$message&wrong_code=true");
exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<head>
```

---

I'm getting "invalid argument" error messages on the result page, and nothing in my email except the sender's IP.

I'm sure I've put the foreach code in the wrong place, but for all intents and purposes, I'm a PHP virgin. This is someone else's basic code.

Thanks so much.

Comment: First of all you´re not sending $dibs wihtin your e-mail. You have to append it to the message for example. Secondly: In which line do you get the invalid arguments error?

Comment: +1 Show here error description and line number as @Tobiask asked

Comment: Sorry, but I'm completely confused. But no matter. In case anyone shows up here, this might be a huge, gigantic help for us PHP virgins: 
  
http://phpfmg.sourceforge.net/. 
  
Took 30 seconds to generate a complete, customizable form with every element I wanted.